# Как закрыть все модальные окна VUE

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap, vuex

Имеется div, в который вложены все модальные окна:

```
<div class="market-modal">
          <new-modal v-show="isShowModal" @close="toggleModal" :style="'padding-bottom:' + (totalAmount > 0 ? '130px' : '75px')" />
          <desc-modal v-show="isShowModalDesc" @close="toggleModalDesc" paddingBottom="50px" />
          <serv-modal v-show="isShowModalServ" @close="toggleModalServ" />
          <cart-modal v-show="isShowModalCart" @close="toggleModalCart" />
          <pay-modal v-show="isShowModalPay" @close="toggleModalPay" />
          <addcard-modal v-show="isShowModalAdd" @close="toggleModalAdd" />
          <success-modal v-show="isShowModalSuccess" @close="toggleModalSuccess" />
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы из последней модалки, по нажатию кнопки, закрывались все открытые до этого модальные окна. Пробовал сделать закрытие всей div, получилось, но потом на неё применялся display:none, который уже никак нельзя было переключить, так как открывается new-modal, по нажатию этой кнопки:

```
<div class="market">
                    <div class="row row-btn-market">
                        <div class="col">
                            <a v-if="checkCourier()" class="button market-button open text-body1-med" @click="toggleModal"
                                >Курьер Маркет
                                <div class="vect-block">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path
                                            d="M3.21664 0.5C2.85831 0.5 2.51664 0.616667 2.19998 0.85C1.88331 1.08333 1.69998 1.38333 1.61664 1.75L0.758309 5.425C0.549975 6.33333 0.716642 7.1 1.24164 7.775C1.34164 7.875 1.44164 7.975 1.53331 8.05833C2.02498 8.53333 2.56664 8.83333 3.34997 8.83333C4.13331 8.83333 4.75831 8.49167 5.22497 8.04167C5.74997 8.55833 6.38331 8.83333 7.16664 8.83333C7.86664 8.83333 8.53331 8.525 8.99997 8.05833C9.56664 8.58333 10.2083 8.83333 10.9166 8.83333C11.6416 8.83333 12.2583 8.55833 12.7833 8.04167C13.2583 8.51667 13.8833 8.83333 14.675 8.83333C15.4666 8.83333 16.025 8.54167 16.5 8.05C16.575 7.975 16.65 7.89167 16.7333 7.80833C17.2833 7.125 17.45 6.33333 17.2416 5.425L16.3833 1.75C16.275 1.38333 16.0833 1.08333 15.775 0.85C15.475 0.616667 15.15 0.5 14.7833 0.5H3.21664ZM14.7416 2.14167L15.6416 5.81667C15.7166 6.175 15.6416 6.5 15.4083 6.79167C15.2 7.05 14.9416 7.16667 14.625 7.16667C14.3666 7.16667 14.1416 7.08333 13.9583 6.88333C13.775 6.69167 13.675 6.46667 13.65 6.2L13.1416 2.16667L14.7416 2.14167ZM3.21664 2.16667H4.85831L4.34998 6.2C4.24998 6.85833 3.92498 7.16667 3.37498 7.16667C3.03331 7.16667 2.77498 7.05 2.59164 6.79167C2.35831 6.5 2.28331 6.175 2.35831 5.81667L3.21664 2.16667ZM6.54164 2.16667H8.16664V6.08333C8.16664 6.375 8.07497 6.625 7.86664 6.85C7.65831 7.06667 7.39997 7.16667 7.08331 7.16667C6.79997 7.16667 6.55831 7.06667 6.36664 6.825C6.17497 6.58333 6.08331 6.33333 6.08331 6.05V5.91667L6.54164 2.16667ZM9.83331 2.16667H11.4583L11.9166 5.91667C11.9833 6.26667 11.9166 6.55833 11.675 6.80833C11.4583 7.05833 11.175 7.16667 10.8333 7.16667C10.575 7.16667 10.3416 7.06667 10.1333 6.85C9.92497 6.625 9.83331 6.375 9.83331 6.08333V2.16667ZM1.49998 9.69167V13.8333C1.49998 14.7583 2.24164 15.5 3.16664 15.5C7.05831 15.5 10.9416 15.5 14.8333 15.5C15.75 15.5 16.5 14.7583 16.5 13.8333V9.70833C16.0416 10.1917 15.4583 10.4667 14.8333 10.5C14 10.525 13.375 10.2833 12.7833 9.70833C12.2833 10.2083 11.6166 10.5 10.9166 10.5C10.1666 10.5 9.49997 10.2 8.99997 9.725C8.52497 10.2 7.87497 10.5 7.14997 10.5C6.39164 10.5 5.72497 10.2083 5.22497 9.70833C4.74164 10.2 4.08331 10.5 3.35831 10.5C2.60831 10.5 2.04998 10.2083 1.49998 9.69167Z"
                                            fill="#0C043F"
                                        />
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, справился)